# Do you have to be married in paradise?

Tags: nikah, allah, jannah, husband, freedom

If you don't get married in this life, do you have to get married in the next if you enter Jannah?

Allah SWT knows me best, what if I do not want to get married? Here, and the next? What if I don't have the time for marriage in this life, and in the next, I don't want a Husband. I can still choose what I want and don't want, right?

Comment: paradise is all about happiness , so you don't have to worry. We should work our way to heaven first , and there everything will be good , there is no sadness or pain . no fear or anxiety.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex A said " if you don't want to be married in next life, it is also fine, and this is your choice to do. And in Heaven you can do whatever you wish, you can get married there, or anything."

I disagree with you because of a hadith "It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: Abu’l-Qaasim (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “**and there will be no one in Paradise who is unmarried**.” Narrated by Muslim (2834)."

So everyone have to get married in Jannah.  You are thinking with mindset of this world that you don't want to married, In Jannah people will be different.  When you enter Jannah you will wanted to get married because how attractive men and women will look and their good character.

**“(there will be) therein all that the ones inner-selves could desire, all that the eyes could delight in, and you will abide therein forever”**

[az-Zukhruf 43:71].

**“Therein you shall have (all) that your inner-selves desire, and therein you shall have (all) for which you ask for”**

[Fussilat 41:31]

As above words from Quran says your desires will be satisfied, one of the desire will be to have a partner.

Why wouldn't you want to get married in this world? when Allah ordered us.

**And if you fear that you will not deal justly with the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice].**

Surah An-Nisa 4:3

**And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought.** [Ar-Rum:21]

And Allah Knows best.

Answer (score 0):

No necessary, you can go to Heaven by believing in every prophet, God the Creator and believe that there is no god but one true God and you must not associate anything or anybody with God and not to worship anyone and anything except Him,  Jinns, Heaven and Hell, being kind with first thing close ones which are your parents and others and stay away from sinful things and things which He prohibited. But if you want you can get married in Paradise. But, if you want to get married in Heaven, it is just fine, if you don't want to be married in next life, it is also fine, and this is your choice to do. And in Heaven you can do whatever you wish, you can get married there, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

it’s not necessary in heaven you can just wish for anything if you want to get married in afterlife that’s fine and if you want to stay single in heaven that’s fine too for example if my heart is telling me to be single in heaven I can just simply ask allah and he’ll take my husband away from me just so that I can be single.